# Solutions Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I think this problem would be incomplete? Do I need to know how much % juice graph juice has?

If I did, would I just have to solve this equation?

$$20x+?(8-x)=40(8)$$

Comment: There is no such thing as graph juice.  I think "graph" is supposed to be "grape", so the second liquid is 100% juice.

Comment: What is graph juice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take graph (probably grape) juice to be $100\%$ juice.  You should specify what $x$ represents.  It looks like the number of liters of punch.  In that case your equation is correct.